# In SQL Server specifically, does Varchar(50) take same amount of space as Varchar(MAX)?

Tags: sql-server-2008

For example, if I wanted to store a 20 byte character string, would a `VARCHAR(50)` field use the same space as a `VARCHAR(MAX)` field ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Varchar(50)` stores a maximum of 50 characters. `Varchar(max)` stores a maximum of **2,147,483,647** characters.
But, `varchar(50)` keeps the 50 character space even if you don't store 50 characters. but `varchar(max)` is flexible to any size. size doesn't matter.

Comment: so just to verify...if i chose Varchar(max) for a database field. And store a 20 character string in one row and a 50 character string in another row. The total space used of the two rows would be 70 bytes, and not 2,147,483,647 X 2 ? But for a Varchar(50), it would be a total of 100 bytes regardless.

Comment: Thats it, its better not to use varchar(max) if you know how many characters are needed.

Comment: from a performance or otherwiser perspective, or the sake of having a clean design ?

Comment: `varchar(50)` will use as many bytes as your string is long that you're storing (+2 bytes overhead) - so if you store a 20 character string, the database uses 22 bytes of storage.

Comment: @darsnet67: there are numerous downsides to just using `varchar(max)` for evertyhing - first of all, you **cannot index** such a column! I suggest you read [What's the Point of Using VARCHAR(n) Anymore?](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/whats-the-point-of-using-varchar%28n%29-anymore/) - really insightful

Comment: @marc_s Updated link to the article you referenced above: [What's the point of using varchar(n) anymore?](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/whats-the-point-of-using-varcharn-anymore/)

Comment: It's not true that "varchar(50) keeps the 50 character space even if you don't store 50 characters." See the comment by marc_s.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you store 20 characters either you use `varchar(20)` or `varchar(max)` both uses the same storage space in SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Here the space has taken in varchar(50) and varchar(max) are same but the different is:-

Advantages:-
If your data size is less than 50 byte means it's good for varchar(50) in database disk space.

Disadvantage:-

If your datasize exceeds more than 50 bytes that time you'll get the error:- String or binary data would be truncated.

So depends on your requirement use the bytes.